# With photoshop timeline animation, how to I animate a large number of layers moving together (linked)?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation

I'm working on the animation of a user interface mock-up for demonstration, and I want to move essentially the entire interface at the same time. I simply link the folders containing all of the layers (hundreds of layers, a complex interface) and drag one, and the whole interface moves. But where I'm confused, is how to tell each layer that it needs to animate that movement? It seems to me that I'll actually have to go to every individual element in the entire interface via the timeline menu and manually turn on position animation on each one.

Timeline animation is the only option, a frame animation isn't viable with the length and complexity of the animation (having to render all of those frames for each change, and not being able to edit / modify / tweak the animation efficiently); I need to do it with timeline.

So I need to do this manually for every single layer I want to move? Or is there some sort of trick I can use to speed this up?

I'm using CS5.1

Comment: You can make layer groups into smart layers and animate that. Or you could use after effects.

Comment: @joojaa You always give me good answers as comments. You dont really care about rep huh?

Comment: No, not much since i hit 20k. But the thing is thats not really a proper answer just a side comment that happens to work in some cases.